# Android webview. Keyboard hide

Tags: android, webview

When clicking on  shows the keyboard. When you click on another area of the screen keyboard is hidden. Is it possible to prevent the hide keyboard when clicking on another area of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to hide the keyboard

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view)// pass your main view {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
    }
```

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView vw = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        vw.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());     // открытие страниц внутри webview
        vw.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  // включили JavaScript
        vw.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);  // включили localStorage и т.п.
        vw.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);  // разрешили доступ к файла 
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this for hide keyboard

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity context) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputManager != null)
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(context.getWindow()
                .getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
    context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

}
```

Comment: Just call this function after webview loded